# Eclipse EE - Why can't the JSP in my web project see a class in my EJB project?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, ear

I'm using Eclipse (Indigo) and GlassFish 3.1.2.

I have a project for EJBs and JPA classes, called `sbwEJBJPA`.

I have an EAR project, called `sbwEAR`.

I have a dynamic web project with JSPs and a Servlet, called `sbw`.

When I export the EAR file from the EAR project, the EAR file contains both sbw.war and sbwEJBJPA.jar.

My `sbw/WebContent/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: sbwEJBJPA.jar
```

The problem is, when I run this simple JSP file:

```
<%@page import="sbw.domain.Website"%>
<% Website w = new Website(); %>
<%= new String("Hello from test.jsp") %>
```

It blows up because it can't see the Website.java class in the sbwEJBJPA.jar, here's the error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
string:///test_jsp.java:6: package sbw.domain does not exist

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 3 in the jsp file: /test.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
string:///test_jsp.java:48: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Website
location: class org.apache.jsp.test_jsp

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 3 in the jsp file: /test.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
string:///test_jsp.java:48: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Website
location: class org.apache.jsp.test_jsp
```

Any ideas why this won't work?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 0):

The Class-Path header only works if the value is in the same archive as the manifest file.  sbwEJBJAP.jar is not in the swb war file.  Get rid of that manifest, go to the web project's Deployment Assembly property page, and mark it as needing the sbwEJBJPA project.

Comment: Thx, when I go to the Deployment Assembly for the sbwEAR project, it says the "Ear Module Assembly" includes `/EarContent`, `sbw / sbw.war`, and `sbwEJBJPA / sbwEJBJPA.jar`.  But it still doesn't work.  Any idea what I'm missing?